# Why does jl test for the second operand of cmp to be less than the first, instead of the other way around?

Tags: history, assembly

Something like this

```
cmp $0, %eax
jl exit
```

jumps to the `exit:` label if the content of register `eax` is `l`ess than `0`.

So it's kind of `jl` applies the `<` operator to the operands of `cmp`, but in reverse order, i.e. `content-of-eax < 0`.

Why is it like this, historically speaking?

Digital computers were born in the left-to-right writing world, no? How comes that `jl` tests for the second operand of `cmp` to be less than the first, instead of the other way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two syntaxes/notations for x86 assembly:

- Intel notation, which puts destinations first.
- GNU or AT&T notation, which puts destinations last.

So the C code `a = b` would correspond to the following assembly patterns:

- Intel: `mov a, b`
- GNU: `mov %b, %a` (move b to a)

Similarly, for a subtraction `a = a - b`:

- Intel: `sub a, b`
- GNU: `sub %b, %a` (subtract b from a)

As a side effect, `sub` will set flags corresponding to the result being equal/greater/less than zero.

The `cmp` is equivalent to a `sub` instruction, except that it discards the result – it has no destination in the typical sense. However, the GNU notation retains the `sub` argument order, improving consistency in the syntax.

The conditional jump instructions like `jl` do not care about operand order. They only look up the value of flags, which might be set by instructions like `cmp`, `test`, or `sub`.

Please also note that assembly code is a human-oriented programming language, not machine code. A line like `cmp $0, %eax` doesn't correspond directly to an actual "cmp" instruction, instead the assembler selects an appropriate encoding. For example, [x86 `cmp` has about 20 different encoding schemas](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmp) depending on operand sizes, whether one operand is an immediate value, or whether the register used is eax/rax. The assembly syntax can also change operand order when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Think of cmp as a subtract operation, followed by checking the result. So you subtract 0 from eax and test if the result is less than zero.

If you wanted to know if x >= y, you’d subtract y from x and check if the result is >= 0. So you’d write sub y, x or cmp y, x.